# @font-face rule , font-family value is ignored

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, font-family

i linked this custom font using @font-face rule

```
@font-face{
font-family: "jf_flatmedium";
src: url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.eot");
src: url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/jf-flat/jf_flat_medium-webfont.svg#jf_flatmedium") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

the browser (chrome & firefox) not rendering the font 'jf_flatmedium' insted it renders the fallback, i double checked the paths for font files.

and on a side notice in the font TTF file the font name is 'jf flat', if i change "font-family" attribute to be 'jf flat' it gets rendered .. so iam guessing this has something to do with the custom font-family name but can't figure out why

UPDATE: one thing i did not refer to in my question that iam displaying Arabic text, i just noticed that on English font is rendered fine . is there anything preventing using a particular font on any language i desire ?

Comment: where is the font from?

Comment: it was a normal TTF font 'JF Flat' i converted to webfont using [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Comment: if you use fontsquirrel, I think they provided you a sample file, you may copy from it to use in your case

Comment: yes this what i always do i copy the provided stylesheet file and modify the file path , but this time it is not working can not figure out why

Comment: you did not forget the @font-face?

Comment: nop it is there , my bad should have added to the question above.

Comment: and they didn't give you a line to put in the HTML file like google do (<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>)??

Comment: no fontsquirrel generate a raw css file to set the font-face and link the font files which i've copied and added in my css file

Comment: your fonts are in the same folder as your CSS?

Comment: No its one directory up then in a folder named fonts , just like the path in the rule indicate

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this i don't know if it will help but i hope so

http://www.fontspring.com/support/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-webfonts-and-browsers?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=help_link&utm_campaign=trouble_shooting_webfonts

Comment: thank you for the video, helped teaching me ways to debug font problems but couldn't find a solution to my problem yet

Answer (score 0):

Fixed , it turned out to be fontsquirrel issue, i tried another webfont generator [transfonter](http://transfonter.org/) and it worked fine.